# Can I remove the stock camera app from iOS 9 or later?

Tags: ios, camera, mobile-device-management

I would like to be able to remove the stock camera app from an iOS device *without* disabling the camera itself (because I would like to replace the camera app with a non-stock app).  I know MDM applications allow the *camera* to be disabled via the iOS mobileconfig restrictions, but can I remove just the (original) app while keeping a functional camera?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: no.

As of iOS 10, here are the stock apps that users can remove:

- Calculator
- Calendar
- Compass
- Contacts (iPhone only, contact information is retained in the Phone
  app)
- FaceTime
- Find My Friends
- Home
- iBooks
- iCloud Drive
- iTunes Store
- Mail
- Maps
- Music (if removed, you won't be able to use it with CarPlay)
- News
- Notes
- Podcasts
- Reminders
- Stocks
- Tips
- Videos
- Voice Memos
- Watch app (you'll have to unpair your Apple Watch before deleting it)
- Weather

As you can see, the stock Camera app is not one of these. I imagine there are ways to forcibly remove it, but you may lose that functionality of your iPhone permanently.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of making the non-Apple Camera app the default, (by swiping the lock screen, for example,) if that is your intention.

On the other hand, if you want more advanced photography abilities, I've found the apps [Camera+](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/camera/id329670577?mt=8) (for full manual control of the camera settings,) CameraBag, and TrueHDR very useful. Using these apps does not require the stock camera be removed at all.

**Disclaimer**: I'm not affiliated with, or have any financial stake in the developers of any of these apps.